# Problems with prepareStatement for variable table name

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

I have a problem with `prepareStatement` in my project
**The problem is** that i want to query tables according to the type of user  i.e  if user is general then access `userlist` table and if user is administrator then access `admin` table
**I have tried like :**

```
String userid=request.getParameter("userid");
String pwd=request.getParameter("pwd");
String check = request.getParameter("radio");
String table;
String status="";
if(check.equals("General"))
table="userlist";
else
table="Administrator";
try{
String sql = "Select status from"+table+"where userid=? and pwd=?";
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Quiz?","root","password");
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1,userid);
ps.setString(2,pwd);
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
```

I get following exception :

> Errorcom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'userid='nawed13593' and pwd='hello'' at line 1

I dont want to use `createStatement` because that will make my project prone to sql injection
Can anyone please help me solve this and the reason why the above exception was thrown?
**Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any spaces before or after your table name.  You will wind up with this, in the "Administrator" case:

```
Select status fromAdministratorwhere userid=? and pwd=?
```

Insert spaces into your SQL statement string:

```
//                              v         v
String sql = "Select status from "+table+" where userid=? and pwd=?";
```